# Stable sub-bundle of a polystable Vector bundle.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let's us say we have a polystable vector bundle $V=W_1\oplus W_2$, where $W_i$'s are stable sub-bundle of degree $0$.

If $W_1\ncong W_2$, then I could easily prove that any stable bundle of $V$ degree $0$ is either contained in either $W_1$ or $W_2$ in the following manner-

If it is a line sub-bundle $L$ then obviously it is contained in either $W_1$ or $W_2$.

If we have a rank 2 degree 0 stable sub-bundle $W$ of $V$. Then we have the following maps $W\rightarrow W_1\oplus W_2\rightarrow W_1$ and $W\rightarrow W_1\oplus W_2\rightarrow W_2$. One of these maps is obviously non-zero and hence isomorphism. Therefore, $W\cong W_1$ or $W\cong W_2$ and hence contained in either either $W_1$ or $W_2$. ($\textbf{Question}$ Can we really conclude that $W$ is either contained in $W_1$ or $W_2$?)

If we have a rank 3 degree 0 stable sub-bundle $W$ of $V$. In a similar manner one can show $W$ is isomorphic to either $W_1$ or $W_2$, which is not possible, hence there is no stable sub-bundle of degree $0$ of rank 3.

Therefore, any stable bundle of $V$ degree $0$ is either contained in either $W_1$ or $W_2$.

If $W_1\cong W_2$, i.e., $V=W\oplus W$ where $W$ is stable bundle of degree $0$. $\textbf{Is it still true that any stable sub-bundle of degree 0 is contained in $W$?}$

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. What about the diagonal embedding of $W$ in $W\oplus W$?

Comment: Sorry, if I am not clear. I just want to prove that if $V=W_1+W_2$ where $W_1,W_2$ are stable bundles of degree $0$ and $W_1$ is not isomorphic to $W_2$ then all stable bundles of degree 0 is either contained in $W_1$ or $W_2$. But that is not the case if $W_1\cong W_2$ (you have already given an example). My question is- I feel that the method of proving that when $W_1\ncong W_2$ all stables bundles of degree $0$ is contained in either $W_1$ or $W_2$ also holds for the case when $W_1\cong W_2$. I must be missing something.